# How to add product reference in product?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am new in prestashop. I want show show my product page like this

[image]

How can I acchive this in prestshop. There is similar functionnalities which I want

http://www.garnier-thiebaut.fr/modeles/128-la-chambre/FIRENZA/BLEU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your request, you can achieve something similar with the built-in "attributes" funcionality. Menu > Catalog > Product Attributes

Have a nice day,

Vlad

Comment: Can you please explain your answer . I very new on prestashop

Comment: Well, using the product attributes function built in prestashop, you can have multiple variations for each product and they will all be displayed on the product page so your customers can choose before adding to cart. Example, if you sell "Sport shoes" you can have the same model in red, black and blue versions as well as different misures, let's say 38, 40, 42. All these attributes will be displayed on the product page. You can also set impact on prices and weight for each attribute so also the final price can be different for each variation even if the product is the same.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply . In prestashop 1.7 I can't find this soultion. I tried but no luck.

Comment: Hi, here's the full instructions on how to use attributes in PS 1.7: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Managing+Product+Attributes